# ES6 import function also imports event handler on.click

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, onclicklistener, es6-modules

I'm using webpack to compile some ES6 modules and I'm pretty new to ES6 in general.
I'm using JQuery to handle a click event like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.slides .file', function(event) {
    var selected_slide_index = getSelectedSlideIndex($(this).data('uid'))
    if (selected_slide_index !== undefined) {
      console.log("removing index", selected_slide_index)
    } else {
      console.log("Adding")
      [...]
    }
  })
})
[..more code here]
export const sideBarRefresh = function() {
  [... code to refresh sidebar here...]
}
```

This works fine until I import sideBarRefresh in another module like so:

```
import { sideBarRefresh } from './search_select'
```

As soon as the import statement is added, then the on.('click') events fires twice in a row every time a click happens, and ends up printing both console statements "Adding" and "removing".
Am I doing something wrong there?

Comment: It sounds like you're loading the file twice. My guess is in the HTML file and as an import, or in the [scripts] setting for webpack

Comment: You mean the import statement imports the entire file and not only the sidebar function ?

Comment: that is correct

Comment: Ok. Looks like moving the event handlers in a separate file from the functions does the trick then, thanks !

Comment: @AlbDum Yes, importing a module loads and evaluates the entire module. The name declarations are just for the exports that should get aliases into the importing module - doesn't matter for evaluation how many you choose there. But the module should never get evaluated twice, even if it is imported multiple times in different locations. Did you actually duplicate the code that installs the event listener elsewhere?

Comment: @Bergi - The OP should realize - if the OP "accidentally" included a `<script>` tag either manually in the HTML text or automagically via WebPack dynamically placing the `<script>` tag into the HTML text that is a separate executing context than the import - The code will execute twice in that arrangement.

Comment: Just for posterity, and OP's reference, here is the reference: https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-source-text-module-record-execute-module

Comment: Throwing this out there, I discovered that all of a file's event listeners are imported when any variable from that file is imported. It doesn't matter what is exported from the file, the event listeners come along with it. This can lead to duplicate events if the module you're importing into also has these event listeners declared.